# SQL Insert if No Record exists

Tags: sql

I'm trying to insert a couple of values into a table via PHP as follows:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1(Field1, Field2)
            Values (?, ?)
            ";
    $stmt = $db-> prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($field1, $field2));
    $stmt->closeCursor();
```

Field 1 is a primary key.

However, I only want to insert Field1 if there is not already an instance of that record for field1 in the table (for example, if there's already a field1 record as 'orange' it should not insert another 'orange' if asked to do so).

I feel like this must be pretty straight forward to do but nothing I'm trying seems to be working.

Comment: So check if the record exists first?

Comment: @RS-It's not letting me comment, so sorry to post this as an answer

Hmmm, I tried that and it only inserted 1 row and everything was blank. Here's my actual code: 

INSERT INTO table1(SKU, Title)
   SELECT (at)SKU, (at)Title FROM dual
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 FROM table1 WHERE SKU=@SKU)
   ";
 $stmt = $db-> prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute(array($SKU, $id));
 $stmt->closeCursor();

The $SKU and $id in the $stmt->execute are variables being created in a foreach loop.

Comment: @user2201011: you should add a tag saying which RDBMS you are working with.

Comment: working with mysql/php

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO table1(Field1, Field2)
SELECT @field1, @field2 from dual
WHERE not exists (select 1 from table1 where field1 = @field1);
--@field1, @field2 are your parameter values
```